# Definition of Natural Numbers with one statement.

Tags: number-theory

Is there a way that we can use mathematical or logical axioms to define natural numbers with one statement? In planar geometry there are several basic notions which can define everything with a finite use of them, same with set theory. How could we define the natural numbers in a similar manner?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _one statement_, but one usually defines natural numbers formally by [Peano axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) and [inductive sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity).

Comment: Well, what I mean is there a way to state, " Natural numbers are defined as *insert basic notions*" or by using a set whose elements are the result of one formula.

Comment: One usually says: "The set of natural numbers is the _smallest_ inductive set", _smallest_ in the sense that it is contained in every other inductive set.

Comment: I don't necessarily like that statement, because there are terms that could be condensed in some manner using basic notions, and that doesn't really define the natural numbers, it gives a property.